# The data I add to this form are not being added to WAMP database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

This is the PHP code I used. When I enter the following HTML form it displays no error messages but data are not being added to the WAMP table

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//$user_name = "root";
//$password = "";
//$database = "cs_project";
//$server = "localhost";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cs_project") or die("Can't connect to the server");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
mysqli_select_db($con,"cs_project") or die("Can't connect to database");

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
$v_number=$_POST["v_number"];
$date=$_POST["date"];
$from=$_POST["from"];
$to=$_POST["to"];
$destination=$_POST["destination"];
$collectpoint=$_POST["collectpoint"];
$payment_method=$_POST["payment_method"];

mysqli_query($linkz,"SELECT * FROM order_table");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO order_table(v_number,date,from,to,destination,collectpoint,payment_method) VALUES('$v_number','$date','$from','$to','$destination','$collectpoint','$payment_method')"); 
if (!$result) {
 die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error()); 
 } 
echo "Data added";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is the HTML code I used. Pease help me :( I'm completely stuck with this. Is it need to input all table columns via the form.? Or is this a problem with my WAMP server or something else.?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Vehicle reservation </title>
<style type="text/css">
th,td{color:#993366; font-family:Candara; font-size:20px; padding:10px; text-align:left}
textarea{color:#33cc33; text-align:center}
h2{color:#008000; font-family:Candara; padding:10px; text-align:center}
input[type=submit],input[type=reset]{background-color:#669900; color:black; padding:12px 25px; text-align:center; border-radius:6px; font-size:16px}
textarea,input[type=text],input[type=date],input[type=time]{border:2px solid orange; border-radius:4px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Please give us the following data to complete your booking...! </h2>
<br>
<form action="newcon.php" method="post" onSubmit="window.open('thanking.html')">
<table style="width:100%" border="0">
<tr> <th> Vehicle number </th>
<td> <input type="text" name="v_number" size="100"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <th> Client ID </th>
<td> <input type="text" name="c_id" size="100"> </td> </tr>
<tr>
<th> Date you want to reserve the vehicle </th>
<td> <input type="date" name="date"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <th> Time </th>
<td> From <input type="time" name="from"> To <input type="time" name="to"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <th> Your destination </th> 
<td> <input type="text" name="destination" size="100"> </td> </tr>
<tr>
<th> Where do you want our cab to be arrived </th>
<td> <textarea name="collectpoint" rows="6" cols="100%">
Please give a brief description of where you want our cab to arrive
We'll contact you via provided phone number for more info 
</textarea> </td> </tr>
<tr>
<th> Payment method </th>
<td> <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="cash"> I'll pay with cash <br>
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="card"> I prefer paying with credit/debit card </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan="2"> Please be informed that you have to pay the full amount via your selected payment method when we arrive at your place.
Please check whether you've provided all the details correctly </td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan="2"> Please comfirm your booking by clicking the button below </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="Comfirm"> </td>
<td> <input type="reset" value="Cancel"> </th> </td>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: note `mysqli_error()` requires the connection -> `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: you are checking `if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) `, but your `<input type="submit" value="Comfirm">` doesn't have a `name="submit"`.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much dude :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php code not run because you used 
    isset($_REQUEST['submit'])
And that return false because 
    
Not has  name='submit'

Use this

```
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="Comfirm">
```